# (0,1) matrix probabilities with column and row sum constraints

Tags: probability, random-matrix

Given an arbitrary length set of values  $c=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]$ and a max value $m=3$, construct a random (0,1) matrix with non-zero rows such that the column sums equal $c$ and the row sums do not exceed $m$. I'm trying to determine the probability the matrix would have $n$ non-zero rows.

Example:

The smallest matrix which satisfies the above is five rows.
\begin{array} {|r|r|r|r|r|}
\hline
0  & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
\hline
0  & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\hline
1  & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
\hline
0  & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
\hline
0  & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\hline
\end{array}

Notice the column sums are $c=[1,2,3,4,5]$ and in this case all rows sum to the maximum allowed of $m=3$. The largest such matrix has 15 rows (sum of $c$) where each row sum is identically equal to one, and all columns are linearly independent.

Progress so far: I started with the maximum size matrix, and randomly permuted the elements in each column independently. Only those which satisfied the row constraints were kept, and all zero rows were ignored. The distribution of non-zero rows remaining from 1e6 simulations that passed both constraints were

```
       1           0
       2           0
       3           0
       4           0
       5           0
       6          77
       7        3423
       8       40505
       9      177455
      10      339183
      11      298041
      12      119691
      13       20396
      14        1215
      15          14
```

(It never found the size-5 matrix, but noticed it could be determined from one of the size 6 matrices it did find)

A few questions:

1. The upper bound is size (sum of c), what is the theoretical lower-bound for arbitrary $c$ and $m$? *Edit: Think it might be $\max \left( \lceil \frac{\Sigma c}{m} \rceil , c \right)$*
2. Is the Monte Carlo procedure which I did the correct way to find the distribution, or is implicitly assuming something which may distort the true distribution?
3. Is a closed-form expression for the correct distribution possible?